# sql query that partitions the data and orders by time and then returns only specific records within a partition

Tags: sql, sql-server

So what I mean exactly is: data is partitioned by name and ordered by date

[image: data is partitioned by name and ordered by date]

I would like now to select only those rows in each partition which are coming  after the row where NO is null and GENRE is null (after the rowNo 3 in case of the provided example)

So result of the query should return rowNo 4 and 5

Query used:

```
select 
    name, no, genre, date,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY name, genre ORDER BY date) 
from 
    sourceTable
```

Comment: can you post the query currently being used and also tag the dbms?

Comment: where rowno > 3 .. ?

Comment: this was just an example @scaisEdge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there is only one row per name where no and genre are `null`, you can use

```
select t1.* 
from tablename t1
join tablename t2 on t1.name = t2.name and t2.no is null and t2.genre is null
where t1.date > t2.date
```

Comment: so obvious:) - thx very much, (brain does not work at the late hour)

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't you just do this?

```
select t.*
from (select name, no, genre, date,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY name, genre ORDER BY date) as rowno
      from sourceTable
     ) t
where rowno > 3;
```

Comment: picture there is just an example. answer is above. what if rowno would be 2, or 1.... I needed a generic approach